# Python, redis: How do I set multiple key-value pairs at once

Tags: python, redis, set, pipeline

I have two lists
keys= [k0,k1, ....kn]
vals= [v0,v1, ....vn]

I can set these key-values on redis in multiple steps doing the following:

`for i in range(0,len(keys)):
   redis_con.set(keys[i], vals[i])`

But this is multiple set operations. 
How can I do this in one async step?

Comment: I think you want this: `{key: value for key, value in zip(keys, vals)}`.

Comment: The question is not about getting a new dataframe. 
It is about setting a number of keys and values in one step, instead of doing a for loop to set one key-value pair at one time.

Comment: If you are asking on doing it in a single redis call, use redis pipeline

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want a single redis call for set ops:

```
pipe = redis_con.pipeline()
for i in range(0,len(keys)):
  pipe.set(keys[i], vals[i])
pipe.execute()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
keys= ["k0","k1"] 
vals= ["v0","v1"]
# use zip or izip based on py 
res = set(zip(keys, vals))
print res
>>> set([('k0', 'v0'), ('k1', 'v1')])
```

Comment: Isn't this deprecated since version 2.6? [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can, also, do it with a custom method like this way:

```
a = [["b", "k", "a"], ["c", "m", "a"], ["a", "j","c"]]
b = [["k","a", "l"], ["l", "f", "c"], ["c", "d", "b"]]

def get_sets(*args):
    final = []
    for v in args:
        for j in v:
            final.append(set(j))
        yield final
        final = []

print(list(get_sets(a,b)))
```

Output:

```
[
  [
   {'b', 'k', 'a'}, {'c', 'a', 'm'}, {'c', 'j', 'a'}
  ],
  [
   {'l', 'k', 'a'}, {'c', 'f', 'l'}, {'c', 'd', 'b'}
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For Django people who landed here, and if you are using django-redis, you can use `.set_many()` method.

```
from django.core.cache import cache
my_dict = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3'}
cache.set_many(my_dict, timeout=60*60)
```

This will create 3 keys in the cache. Internally it uses [redis pipeline](https://github.com/jazzband/django-redis/blob/5.2.0/django_redis/client/default.py#L491).